# Hbase filter using Pyspark

Tags: filter, pyspark, hbase

I am trying to read and filter data from hbase via pyspark. So far, able to do scan, range scans (using start and stop). However, clueless on how to use the filters. e.g.valuefilter, ColumnPrefixFilter etc..

say using the class hbase.filter.FilterBase.filterRowKey

While googling, found something similar was asked previously but unanswered. 
**[Spark: How to use HBase filter e.g QualiferFilter by python-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074716/spark-how-to-use-hbase-filter-e-g-qualiferfilter-by-python-api)**

Note: Using cloudera distribution and need to do this via pyspark (heard it can easily be done via scala/java)

Following is the code:-

```
host = "host@xyz.com"
keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"

valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"

conf_read = {"hbase.master.kerberos.principal": "hbase/_HOST@xyz.com", \
        "hbase.rpc.protection":"privacy", \
        "hadoop.security.authentication": "kerberos", \
        "hadoop.rpc.protection": "privacy", \
        "hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal": "hbase/_HOST@xyz.com" , \
        "hadoop.security.authentication": "kerberos", \
        "hbase.security.authentication": "kerberos", \
        "hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort": "2181", \
        "zookeeper.znode.parent": "/hbase", \
        "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host, \
        "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "namespace:tablename", \
        #"hbase.mapreduce.scan.row.start": "row2", \ --this works
        #"hbase.mapreduce.scan.row.stop": "row4", \ --this works 
        "hbase.filter.FilterBase.filterRowKey":"row3"} --this does not

testdata_rdd = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
        keyConverter=keyConv,
        valueConverter=valueConv,
        conf=conf_read)

output = testdata_rdd.collect()

print output
```